# How to deploy Kubernetes pods across Windows OS versions with Hyper V on Windows 1803?

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, hyper-v, windows-server

I have a simple one master (Ubuntu 1604), one worker (Windows Server 1803) kubernetes cluster.

I also have a Jenkins build agent (Windows Server 2016) that builds a .NET docker image in a pipeline.

Base Image: FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2016

My goal is to create a deployment on the kubernetes worker (Windows Server 1803) using the image that the Jenkins build agent (Windows Server 2016) built. However, since Windows Images must match the exact Windows version they are running on, this cannot currently be done out of the box.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility

> "Windows Server Containers are blocked from starting when the build number between the container host and the container image are different"

However, from that same link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility) it describes that this is possible using Hyper-V.

> Unlike standard Windows containers, which share the kernel between containers and the host, each Hyper-V isolated container has its own instance of the Windows kernel. Because of this you can have different OS versions in the container host and image (see compatibility matrix below).

I used docs from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/install-the-hyper-v-role-on-windows-server, and ran the following and restarted the Windows host to try to enable Hyper-V:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V -ComputerName <computer_name> - 
IncludeManagementTools -Restart
```

Then, again from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility,

> To run a container with Hyper-V isolation, simply add the tag --isolation=hyperv to your docker run command.

I attempted this by RDPing onto the 1803 worker and running the following docker command, and got same error. (Container OS has to match Host OS)

```
docker run microsoft/iis:ltsc2016 --isolation=hyperv
```

Overall, I was not able to run a docker container with hyperv, and I can't seem to find anything on how to "activate" or use hyperv with a kubernetes deployment yml file either.

Any thoughts are vastly appreciated!

More details:

Cluster Set up using: https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=E2B6765015E5FA01!339&ithint=file%2cdocx&app=Word&authkey=!AGvs_s_hWs7xHGs

Above link was an updated set of instructions on the feedback section of this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/getting-started-kubernetes-windows, which did not work for me.

Comment: have you tagged the image properly?  As specified in the tutorial you have linked:
`Prepare Infrastructure Image

I recommend you pick an image and double-check that it works for your specific build. Otherwise, your pods may later be stuck in “ContainerCreating” status indefinitely. There are three steps to this: pulling the image, tagging it as microsoft/nanoserver:latest, and running it. For Windows Server 2019 images simply adjust the docker pull command below to match your specific insider build`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I was able to successfully run a docker image on the 1803 worker using the :1803 tag, but my goal now is to use hyperv to run a Windows Server 2016 image on an 1803 kubernetes worker. This should be possible according to the chart at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility, but can't get it to work. I also edited my question for more clarity. Thanks again!